# How much arithmetic can Predicative Second-Order EFA do?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, foundations, reverse-math, ultrafinitism

As discussed in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150454/can-the-burgess-hazen-analysis-of-predicative-arithmetic-be-extended-to-transfin), I'm trying to find what the result would be of applying a Feferman-Scutte-like analysis to the predicativism of Edward Nelson and Charles Parsons, who believe that mathematical induction is impredicative.  The first step of such an analysis was done in a [paper by Burgess and Hazen](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-39/issue-1/Predicative-Logic-and-Formal-Arithmetic/10.1305/ndjfl/1039293018.full).

Basically, we start out with Robinson's $Q$, and then we add (ramified) predicative second-order logic, which is like regular second-order logic except that the comprehension schema is broken up into levels.  The comprehension schema for level $0$ sets only allows formulas with no quantification over sets.  The schema for level $1$ sets allows quantification over level $0$ sets.  For any natural number $n$, the schema for level $n+1$ sets allows quantification over sets of level $n$ and below.  Now Burgess and Hazen essentially showed that predicative second-order Robinson arithmetic implies exponential function arithmetic, also known as $EFA$.  (Actually, they showed that it implies Robinson arithmetic + induction for formulas with bounded quantifiers + the totality of exponentiation, but I'm pretty sure $EFA$ is a conservative extension of that.)

But there's no particular reason why we should stop at finite levels.  For instance, we could have a comprehension schema for level $\omega$ sets, which allows quantification over sets of any finite level.  And so on, for bigger and bigger transfinite ordinals.  The question is just what ordinals do we use?  Following Feferman-Schutte, we only allow an ordinal $\alpha$ if we can show that it is "predicatively acceptable" (using lower-level comprehension schemata).

So how do we begin?  For starters, as discussed above predicative second-order Robinson arithmetic with finite levels implies $EFA$, and the proof theoretic ordinal of EFA is $\omega^3$, so we can say that the ordinals less than $\omega^3$ are predicatively acceptable.

So now the question becomes, if we take $EFA$ and we add predicative second-order logic with comprehension schemes for levels up to $\omega^3$, how much of first-order arithmetic can we prove?  This would help in making a dent in my MathOverflow question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

EDIT: Someone mentioned in responding to my MathOverflow question that [this paper by Leivant](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science/article/abs/stratified-polymorphism-and-primitive-recursion/964CF00D018D3D8FE8DCBFFBE5A8DB1C) shows that "predicative stratification in the polymorphic lambda calculus using levels $<\omega^\ell$ leads to definability of functions in Grzegorczyk's $\mathscr E_{\ell+4}$".  I'm not that familiar with the lambda calculus, so can someone confirm that this implies that $EFA$ with predicative second-order logic with comprehension schemes for levels up to $<\omega^3$ proves that all functions in Grzegorczyk's $\mathscr E_{7}$ are total?  If that were true then the proof-theoretic ordinal of this system would be $\omega^7$, so it would be a first step in doing a Feferman-Schutte-like analysis.  (And by similar methods, I think we can go to $\omega^{11}$, $\omega^{15}$, etc, all the way up to $\omega^\omega$, the proof-theoretic ordinal of $PRA$.)